# Does @synchronized(self) create a block where the self prefix is unecessary on properties?

Tags: objective-c, synchronized, self, declared-property

I have read something in some foreign code and I want to check my assumption:

`@synchronized(self)` is used to get rid of the `self` prefix when setting a property.

So in my example below, I'm setting the `strText` of the instance, not just a local variable, right?

```
- (void)myfunction{
    NSString * strText = @"var in function";
    @synchronized(self)
    {
         strText = @"var class (self.strText)";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Please read this [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1)

> The `@synchronized()` directive locks a section of code for use by a
>   single thread. Other threads are blocked until the thread exits the
>   protected code—that is, when execution continues past the last
>   statement in the `@synchronized()` block.
>
> The `@synchronized()` directive takes as its only argument any
>   Objective-C object, including `self`.

As [Massimo Cafaro pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633229/603977):
"It’s safest to create all the mutual exclusion objects before the application becomes multithreaded, to avoid race conditions."

Comment: The documentation link is now obsolete. Please refer to this one :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1

Comment: @cescofry, Yes that link was outdated. I update my answer with your given link. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> @synchronized(self) is used to get rid of the self. prefix.
>
> So in my example I set the strText not in the function I set it in the
>   class.

Two concepts are being conflated.

1. `@synchronized(self) { ... }` only locks the block using the `self` object as the semaphore.
2. In Objective-C, there is nothing like a hypothetical `with` statement as in other languages  that removes the need for `self.whatever` to be just `whatever`.  Might want to take the Stanford CS193P online course to brush up on the language.

Comment: Why this answer? It may 'answer' the question but--no offense--you just come across as terse and unhelpful.

Comment: @synchronized has no effect on whether or not you need a "self." prefix. They are unrelated in any way.

Comment: This is the only answer of the three that actually addresses the misunderstanding in the question @Matt. The other two just parrot the docs about `@synchronized()`

Comment: @JoshCaswell Tracking, but my comment is from 2013, and in 2014 Barry edited the post to actually say something besides "you're wrong".  I suppose you're right that this post now "answers the question" better.

Comment: Oop, sorry Matt, I definitely should have thought to look at the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

> In a multithreaded environment if more than one thread tries to access
>   same memory address may cause a “Race Condition”, to avoid such kind
>   of conditions you should use “Mutex Lock(Mutual Exclusion)” nothing
>   but blocking or restricting or locking n number of threads to access
>   same memory address or content at a same point of time and allowing
>   only one thread at an instance of time. This can be achieved in
>   Objective C by using @synchronized directive.

Example:
Generally while implementing Singleton design pattern or class you will see some kind of code snippet like below in any iOS projects,

```
+(id)getSingletonInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (singletonObj == nil)
        {
            singletonObj = [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return singletonObj;
    }
}
```